# how to handle in empty string from reading a file in java

Tags: java, file-handling

the project is to read from a file ex2.
I used Delimiter to separate to two strings.
but when I get to line 4(complex#) I get a NoSuchElementException().
I want to read that line from the file but, to make my own Exception.
and not NoSuchElementException().
how can I do that?

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
            List<Polynom<Double>> listDouble;
            List<Polynom<Complex>> listComplex;
            SortedSet<Polynom<Double>> setDouble;
            SortedSet<Polynom<Complex>> setComplex;
    
            int countLines =1;
            Scanner lineScan = null;
            String line = null;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("ex2.txt"));
            while (sc.hasNextLine()){
                try{
                    line = sc.nextLine();
                    lineScan = new Scanner (line);
                    lineScan.useDelimiter("#");
                    String type = lineScan.next();
                    String value = lineScan.next();
    
    } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
'''
this is the file ex2:
complex#[7,(1+5i)]
double#[0,1.0][3,-2]
aaa#[0,1.0][3,-2]
complex#
double#[0,1.0][3,-2]#[-2,1.0]
double#[-2,1.0]
complex#[7,-(1+5i)]
complex#7,(1+5i)
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you've read a line from the file, you can use String.split ("delimiter") -> Returns an Array.

It is not necessary to scan a line that you already have in memory.

```java
int countLines = 1;
Scanner lineScan = null;
String line = null;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("ex2.txt"));
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    try {
        line = sc.nextLine();              
        String[] array = line.split("#");
                
        if(array.length == 1){
            System.out.println("Line (1 element): " + array[0]);
        } else if(array.length == 2){
            System.out.println("Line (2 elements): " + array[0] + " / " + array[1]);
        } else if(array.length == 3){
            System.out.println("Line (3 elements): " + array[0] + " / " + array[1] + " / " + array[2]);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your solution.
I still want to keep this two lines
String type = line Scan.next(); String value = line Scan.next();
so that i can split using a delimiter("#")
but I will have me own exception.

Comment: Then you just have to add an additional catch block. Edited Solution

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
    int countLines =1;
    Scanner lineScan = null;
    String line = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("ex2.txt"));
    while (sc.hasNextLine()){
        try{
            line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] arr = line.split("#");
            if(arr.length < 2) {
                throw MyCustomException;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This checks if the array you got from `line.split("#")` has less than 2 values and throws your own exception if it does.

Comment: thank you for your solution. I still want to keep this two lines String type = line Scan.next(); String value = line Scan.next(); 
so that i can split using a delimiter("#") but I will have me own exception.